# Fragment: Avoiding getActivity() to return null by overriding OnActivityCreated?

Tags: android, android-context

I must call `getActivity` in my fragment. I have read on Stackoverflow *e.g.* that we could store the activity in a class/object attribute, but I have read that it's a bad practice too.

Would it be possible to override `onActivityCreated` in the fragment, and simply execute all my logic (which requires `getActivity`) in this callback?

It should avoid any `NullException`.

Comment: `OnCreateView` - should only create view. `OnViewCreated` - initialise view objects and add any click listeners. `OnActivityCreated` - Core business logic. `OnResume` - Lifecyle dependant business logic. Hope that helps. P.S. Its still better to have null check in Asynchronous tasks like making a network call.

Answer (score 0):

I would say use a WeakReference to your activity, you can use it to access the activities members from a fragment

```
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference
```